# iOS UITableViewCell accessory on the left side?

Tags: ios, uitableview

For my app, I want a number of cells that can have both a checkmark and a detail disclosure button. That is, I want them to appear exactly like the Wi-Fi network selection in the iOS settings: checkmark on the left side, content in the middle, and detail disclosure button on the right.

Is there a proper way to do this, or am I supposed to just use an image of a checkmark in the image part of the cell content? If you know of any sample code doing this sort of thing, please point me to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard styles for UITableViewCell do not include one that works as you want, so you'll have to do this yourself by manually adding a subview to the cell.

You could use the [example here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by simply prepending a couple of unicode symbols:
[Put checkmark in the left side of UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755506/put-checkmark-in-the-left-side-of-uitableviewcell/12664922#12664922)

Comment: There are no unicode characters that are identical to iOS checkmark, so you'll end up with a weird/non-standard looking UI.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a image to the standard imageView of the cell then a tapGesture on it ?

Here is how I did in willDisplayCell:

```
//Reset the cell
cell.imageView.image=nil;
cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

for(UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in cell.imageView.gestureRecognizers)
    [cell.imageView removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

//Add the gesture
cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(geolocationAction:)];
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```