# How to get checkmark on left side of UITableViewCell on iOS 7, like in Settings?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

In iOS *Settings > Wi-Fi* for example, the cell's checkmark is on the left (of the connected network), with the disclosure button on the right.

I need this.  Is there a standard way in iOS 7 to get this?

Comment: custom cell and creating that in code might be a solution.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey Any idea where I can get iOS 7's checkmark image?

Comment: here is a translucent background image link but it is in black. http://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&docid=heBUi9GW_WD8nM&tbnid=qrmJngV8JVYCDM:&ved=0CAMQjhw&url=http%3A%2F%2Ficons8.com%2F2014%2F01%2F31%2Fios-7-icons-ok-cancel-close-redo-undo%2F&ei=smX2Uo_mE8K-kQf6soDYBg&bvm=bv.60983673,d.aWc&psig=AFQjCNGErQbrVTFTVId83jcaceq0eULarQ&ust=1391965964104752

Comment: @XCodeMonkey That's a differently shaped checkmark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using a custom cell, you may prefer `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` styled cell. It has an optional `imageView`, use checkmark as an image.

Or, you can use unicode symbols for checkmarks. It is a pretty neat solution and greatly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12664922/755845).

Comment: I already found that unicode answer, and it's indeed neat (I saved the link).  But unicode does not have the standard/blue iOS checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to put an accessory on the left, it seems that they just use cell's imageView for the checkmark and built-in detail disclosure indicator on the right.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exact solution but something close what iOS is doing in their WiFi listing, using only unicode character for checkmark and attributed string to set color to checkmark.

```
NSString *strCellText = @"This row is selected";
NSString *strCheckMarkUnicode = @"\u2713";
NSString *strFinalText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",strCheckMarkUnicode,strCellText];

NSMutableAttributedString *strAttributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:strFinalText];
NSRange range=[strFinalText rangeOfString:strCheckMarkUnicode];

[strAttributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                          value:[UIColor blueColor]
                          range:range];

_cellOne.textLabel.attributedText = strAttributedText;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 and later, place this guy in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

That's it!

Comment: have you read a question? your code will enable multiple selection . thats it

Comment: Multiple selection during editing puts check boxes on the left.