# how do I left align a button in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I align the table cell button to the left instead of the right? Below is the code I am using to create the UIButton. Thanks.

```
cell.accessoryView = [self getButton: @"icon.png"];

...

- (UIButton*)getButton: (NSString*)icon {
    UIImage *image = (true) ? [UIImage   imageNamed:icon] : [UIImage imageNamed:icon];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return button;

}
```

Comment: From my past experience, the best way to accomplish this is to roll your own table view cell or add the button as a subview and not using the accessoryView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the button as an accessory view, which cannot be put on the left. See this question, it is almost exactly the same:

[iOS UITableViewCell accessory on the left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841426/ios-uitableviewcell-accessory-on-the-left-side)

Answer (score 0):

Then you can muck with the frame of the button.

```
UIButton *cellButton = [self getButton:@"icon.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellButton];
```